# How to normalise 2 images in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have 2 images. 1st is taken in bright light and the 2nd in dark. How to make these 2 images look like they are taken at same place. What operation should be done on the images?
I am using OpenCV in android.

Comment: May be color transfer? http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/06/30/super-fast-color-transfer-images/     More advanced: http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~turkel/imagepapers/ColorTransfer.pdf

Comment: Were they taken in the same place or not?

Comment: No...They are taken at different places

Comment: But the background is same i.e. White

Comment: Do you have an example of what you are trying to achieve? The simplest method for creating similar appearance is by using histogram equalization